# How to print data stored in session from php?

Tags: php, session, authentication

After a user logs in they are redirected to their profile page. Where in that profile page they'll be able to see their username, and email that is associated with that account printed out on screen so if other people visit their profile they can see that contact info.

```
public function Login($username, $password){
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT username, password, email FROM users WHERE BINARY username = ? AND BINARY password = ?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1,$username);
        $stmt->bindParam(2,$password);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
            $email = $stmt->fetchColumn(4);
            $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
            header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/dev/profile.php');
        }else{
            echo "Incorrect username or password please try again.";
        }               
    }else{
        echo "Must type a username and password to login.";
     }      
   }
}//End of login function
```

That is the function that does the login and it is supposed to set the sessions, right now only the username sessions actually gets printed out in the profile, email does not show.

```
<?php echo '<h1>'.htmlentities($_SESSION["username"]).'</h1>'; ?>
<?php echo '<h1>'.htmlentities($_SESSION["email"]).'</h1>'; ?>
```

This is how I am printing the sessions and like I said before only username is getting printed I'm out of ideas, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be in the parameter of the fetchColumn method. Try this:

```
$email = $stmt->fetchColumn(2);
```

Comment: That did the trick, but how come? I put 4 because I thought you had to count the number of columns in my database and email happened to be 4.

Comment: fetchColumn parameter is the order of the fields written in your query, not the order of the columns of your database. Personally, I think it's a bad idea to use this method for more than one field.

Answer (score 0):

start php session in your php code

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

and then set the values in the session array.

Comment: He has already used session_start() otherwise he could not echo username from session.

Comment: Which session array? And yea I'm already starting the session in both the login php and profile php. And the username prints out just as I want just not the email

Answer (score 0):

You can print the session variable this way -

```
<?php

session_start();

$NAME=$_SESSION['l_id'];

echo "Name is ".$NAME;
?>
```

Comment: That will not help. You do not need to use variable to echo session.